# Consulta Sqlite3 en python devuelve una lista con varios valores pero longitud 1 que no puedo mostrar por índices

Tags: python, lista, python-3.7, sqlite3, indices

El problema que tengo es que tras realizar una consulta a una base de datos en sqlite3 con python, esta, me devuelve una lista de longitud1 con varios valores de las columnas, si quiero mostrar uno de esos valores con un índice ([3] por ejemplo) me da un fuera de rango pues la lista solo tiene un elemento.

Esta es la función que hace la búsqueda y que devuelve una lista con un solo elemento

```
def buscar_datos(nombre):
    try:
        con = sqlite3.connect(db)
        cur = con.cursor()
        busqueda = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Articulos WHERE Nombre= ?', [nombre])
        con.commit()
        res = busqueda.fetchall()
        longitud = len(res)
        print("long ", longitud)
        con.close()
        return res

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Error8: ", e)
```

Lo que pretendo hacer es mostrar la columna 3 por ejemplo, pero no encuentro la razón por la que la lista que debería tener 6 elementos, solo tiene uno, conteniendo los 6 y por tanto solo puedo mostrarlos todos con un [0]

No se si me he explicado bien, perdonad, pero estoy en fase novato.
Gracias por ayudarme! :)

Comment: Intenté replicar las condiciones con un sqlite que tengo, y funciona perfecto. Para probar cambié `nombre` por `id < ?`, le mandé `[8]` y me trajo 7 resultados, justo como lo esperaba. ¿Estás seguro que la consulta SQL devuelve más de un valor? Ejecútala directamente en tu editor sqlite a ver qué devuelve.

Comment: @ aeportugal Para esta consulta:
 SELECT * FROM Articulos WHERE Nombre = 'Peras' 
me devuelve:
id id_familia Nombre PVP Stock Alta Baja
6 Frutas Peras 300.0 0.39 02-06-22 

Ejecución terminada sin errores.
Resultado: 1 filas devueltas en 7ms
En la línea 1:
SELECT * FROM Articulos WHERE Nombre = 'Peras'

Comment: La salida que me muestra Pycharm en consola si hago un print(longitud) y un  print(res) es:
long  1
res 0 [(6, 'Frutas', 'Peras', 300.0, 0.39, '02-06-22', '')]
Observad los corchetes y despues el parentesis...

Por cierto, como edito el codigo en los comentarios de respuesta? el Ctrl+k no funciona!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Actualicé la respuesta**

Si tienes estos datos:

```
# col1  col2    col3    col4  
# 6     3   2   7
# 1000  6   5   5
# 2     8   9   4
# 9     3   5   5
```

Entonces puedes hacer esto:

```
import sqlite3

def buscar_valor(valor):
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("./datos.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("select * from tabla1 where col1=?",[valor])
        row = cur.fetchone()
        conn.close()
        return row

    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        return [e]

datos = buscar_valor(1000)

print(datos)
# (1000, 6, 5, 5)

# Si quieres posición 3,
dato_numero_4 = datos[3]
print(dato_numero_4)
# 5
```

cur.fetchall() te está dando un dato, a saber, una lista (de una lista o más). Para aislar la única fila, necesitas hacerle referencia al primer elemento de lo que produjo fetchall().

Según Dante S, es mejor coger 1 sola fila:

```
row = cur.fetchone()
```

Como devuelve toda la fila en forma de un tuple, accedes el valor que quieres según el índice del valor/columna de la fila de vuelta.

```
dato_numero_4 = datos[3]
```

Comment: Por qué usar cursor.fetchall en lugar de cursor.fetchone?

Comment: Ok @Joe Collentine y ahora como recorreria lo que me devuelve? porque entiendo que lo me devuelve la consulta es una fila en formato lista no tupla, pero cuando trato de capturar uno de los datos de esa lista que me devuelve me da un index fuera de rango porque como veis solo tiene una posicion [0] y ahi es donde tengo el problema

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta

Comment: @DanteS. pues la verdad, porque pensaba que era la forma en que me mostraría todos los registros para una búsqueda dada, pero en realidad ya probé con fetchone y no me cambia nada respecto a la cuestión

Answer (score 0):

[RESUELTO] El caso es que que efectivamente poniendo fetchone, si me respeta el indice y puedo extraer por posicion, de hecho al hacer un len me da 7 y no 1 como con el fetchall, por tanto ahora si puedo extraer los valores de la lista de forma independiente.
Os agradezco la ayuda y las sugerencias, entre todos me habéis ayudado a resolverlo.
Muchas gracias!  ;)

Comment: A la orden  @rgmagritte :)